# Java headless browser compatible with version 1.7

Tags: java, headless-browser

I'm looking for a java headless browser to make automated test for my server, unfortunatly i can't change the version of java, which is the 1.7.

So far i tried with jbrowserdriver and ui4j, but they are not compatible with my java version.

It would be great if someone knows an older version of those libraries that are compatible with the 1.7 but any other library for java is good.

Comment: Any Java application written since 1.0 should run under Java 7, unless it was compiled for Java 8. Are you sure you have a problem? Off topic.

Answer (score 1):

There are two good options that I can recommend:

- [htmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net): written in Java, works well;
- [Selenium WebDriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/), together with PhantomJS.

I've tested both for headless browsing, and both are pretty good. My project is in Java 7 also, so they're compatible.

Comment: It looks like you're mixing apples and oranges. Selenium WebDriver is "a collection of language specific bindings to drive a browser". HtmlUnit is a headless web browser. Selenium WebDriver can be used to drive either jBrowserDriver or htmlUnit, but it is not a browser per se. W.r.t. htmlUnit, I was very fond of it for a time, but gave up on it some years ago as it seemed to be falling behind hopelessly as the web moved to a more interactive, JavaScript-based page model. I am looking into PhantomJS now and keeping jBrowserDriver as a backup option.

Comment: Perhaps my phrasing was not perfect: what I meant, as the question implied the use of Java 7, is the use of PhantomJS (which is, of course, the headless browser) with the proper Selenium WebDriver implementation.

Comment: I'm sure that's true, I just wanted to clarify the point for anyone reading the answer and mention jBrowserDriver in addition to the valid options you listed.